# Can you use named queries on Elasticsearch with PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I know you can use named queries in Elasticsearch to test which document matched the best in Kibana but I'm running Wordpress with Jetpack search which uses elasticsearch PHP (v2.4) and I want to be able to test my queries and return the named queries on each result so I can better understand that my queries returned what I had intended. This is how it's done in Elasticsearch (json):

```
...
    "must": [
        {
            "match": {
                "body": {
                    "query": "Will Smith",
                    "_name": "match_will_smith"
                }
            }
        }  
    ],
    "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "body": {
              "query": "Will Smith",
              "slop": 5,
              "_name": "should_match_phrase_will_smith_with_slop"
            }
          }
        },
    ]...
```

Result:

```
"matched_queries" : [
    "match_will_smith",
    "should_match_phrase_will_smith_with_slop"
]
```

That would be awesome if I could get the value of the "matched_queries" object and print it to my php page on every result to I can see what each article is matching. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: From the code of the plugin ([here](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/_inc/lib/jetpack-wpes-query-builder/jetpack-wpes-query-builder.php) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/_inc/lib/jetpack-wpes-query-builder/jetpack-wpes-query-parser.php)) it does not seem like Jetpack supports `_name`. Can you access the logs of Elasticsearch and possibly do the JSON queries directly to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing is using `explain` parameter in your query
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

it would give how the score of your document was calculated by using which sections of your query

but I would not use it in production environment